# Capturing Ant <javadoc> task output

Tags: ant, javadoc

Is it possible to capture the warnings that Javadoc prints when run via the `javadoc` Ant task?  I don't see an output attribute such as the one in the  task.  There seem to be warnings that Checkstyle just isn't catching and it'd be nice to snag that output in a file.

Seems strange this wouldn't be capturable, hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

~*~*~*~ **EDIT** (answer below) ~*~*~*~

It would appear the Ant <record> task is exactly what I was looking for.  See [the Ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html).

```
<target name="generate.docs">
    <record name="javadoc.log" action="start"/>
    <javadoc ... />
    <record name="javadoc.log" action="stop"/>
<target/>
```

Comment: Now, what are you doing with this file?  Do you have a way to say pull out the warning/error messages to display - Like Maven does?

Comment: More or less the same.  The CI server Hudson will parse those messages out and place them as a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is possible using the `<exec>` tag ([reference here](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#shell-redirect-1))... it would probably be a royal pain, but it might be possible to exec the javadoc executable and reconstruct the command arguments necessary to generate the javadoc. As a great big honking strike against, though, it appears that only uses your natural shell redirect, so building on both Win32 and Linux would require some special-case mojo.

It may be worth it to [write your own task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) to do the job; either the `<redirect>` tag as Roboprog has mentioned above, or extending the Javadoc task...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the previous redirection answer was down voted due to unstated requirement to do this every time via the build.xml script commands.

Yep.  The feature does not seem to be there in the  task.  A better question might be:  Is there a task / tag in Ant that will redirect ALL output from ANY nested tags?  Such a task/tag would save System.out and/or System.err, set them to create or append to a file, then restore them at the end of the block.

Something like:

```
<redirect file='foo.txt' append='true'>
  <anytag you='want' />
</redirect>
```

Comment: I think all of the cool kids are hacking on Maven plugins now, though, so this will likely not happen soon.  Me, I still miss "make"  :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can execute javadoc as a Java class with the com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main class, calling the execute method (it is in the tools.jar included in the JDK), so you could wrap a java class that you call from the Ant java task, which allows redirection of output. you will have to reconstruct the javadoc command line arguments yourself, instead of having the niceties of the Ant task, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else is still interested - the Ant `javadoc` task can be very easily be retrofitted with an option `outputFile` to store the generated messages e.g. to a file:

```
public class MyJavaDoc extends org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javadoc{

    private File _outFile;

    private Writer _writer;

    /**
     * The file to write error output to.
     */
    public void setOutputFile(File outFile) {
        _outFile = outFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        if (_outFile == null) {
            throw new BuildException("Missing 'outputFile' parameter.");
        }
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_outFile)) {
            _writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            try {
                super.execute();
            } finally {
                _writer.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new BuildException("Cannot write error output: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String msg, int msgLevel) {
        if (msgLevel <= Project.MSG_WARN) {
            try {
                _writer.write(msg);
                _writer.write("\n");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new IOError(ex);
            }
        }
        super.log(msg, msgLevel);
    }

}
```